# exemplo de checkout de iugu para rails não funciona

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagamento-online, rails4

Estou tentando fazer funcionar este exemplo do iugu: https://iugu.com/referencias/exemplo-de-checkout

Eu tenho uma conta no iugu em modo de teste.

Eu segui os passos deste tutorial, fiz as modificações necessárias como colocar o meu account id no lugar definido e a api key no controller. Estou em modo de testes e utilizando a api key de testes. Estou utilizando o cartão de crédito de testes o 4111 1111 1111 1111. Porém o retorno de charge.success é sempre false e não há uma mensagem de erro.

Comment: Carlos, tudo certo? (: Você compartilha, por favor, seu *source code* conosco para vermos o que está rolando?

Comment: tudo bom? Chegou a olhar o que tem em charge.errors? Esse é o objeto onde guardamos os erros que voltam da API. Abs, Marcelo

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema a partir dos dados de erro em charge.errors.

Minha sugestão é pessoal da iugu alterar o código do exemplo de modo a logar os dados de erro caso a transação falhe. 

Quando eu estava tentando resolver este problema, eu cheguei a entrar em contato com o suporte online do iugu algumas vezes para obter este tipo de informação, mas ninguém conseguiu me responder adequadamente.

Um exemplo básico de checkout com este tipo de informação salva um bom trabalho de suporte de vocês da iugu e meu também. 
Fica a dica ;)